# MSVS2008 to MSVS2003 Conversion (Google Protobuf)

Tags: visual-studio, converters, protocol-buffers

I have to get [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) running on Visual Studio 2003, but it was built for Visual Studio 2008. Does anyone know wether that is possible and if so, how? 
I did some research and found, that sometimes just renaming the projects version number in the .sln should help, but for me it didn't. I am clueless on how to continue from here. Some kind of converters would help maybe?

Thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: Okay, it doesn't seem to work very well. Looks like Protobuf needs at least Visual Studio 2005: 

c:\CustomMods\include\google\protobuf\stubs\atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.h(46) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "We require at least vs2005 for MemoryBarrier"

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you're unlikely to get this working; even when protobuf was released in 2008 the oldest VS it supported was 2005, and software tends to grow dependencies on newer features over time. Out of morbid curiosity, why are you stuck on a 12-year-old compiler?

Comment: The company I am working for hasn't migrated its environment for a long time. Didn't get it to work, but since my question was posted the migration was successful. Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible to run Google Protobuf with the MSVS03 Compiler. The following error occures when trying to do so:

```
...\include\google\protobuf\stubs\atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.h(46) : fatal error C1189: #error : "We require at least vs2005 for MemoryBarrier
```

Therefore we need at least MSVS05.